# Using FontAwesome icon to replace png as a source

Tags: html, css, svg, font-awesome, ghost-blog

I wonder if anyone can help me!

I have SiteSearch360 running on my site and I'm using a full screen search bar that is triggered by clicking an image of a magnifying glass.

I want to update the default image `(src="https://cdn.sitesearch360.com/ss360-search-icon.png")` with my own Font Awesome icon to match the others being used on the site.

When I replace the source with my font awesome code `<i class="fas fa-search"></i>`the icon appears broken and isn't clickable, however when the icon isn't used in the SiteSearch360 config it displays perfectly fine. I've tried about 100 variations of the code and would really appreciate any help to get this working.

Many thanks

**site-nav.hbs**

```
<nav class="site-nav">
<div class="site-nav-left-wrapper">
    <div class="site-nav-left">
        {{#if @site.logo}}
            <a class="site-nav-logo" href="{{@site.url}}"><img src="{{@site.logo}}" alt="{{@site.title}}" /></a>
        {{else}}
            <a class="site-nav-logo" href="{{@site.url}}">{{@site.title}}</a>
        {{/if}}
        <div class="site-nav-content">
            <div class="mobileShow"> Scroll</div> 
            {{#if @site.navigation}}{{navigation}}
            {{/if}}
            {{#is "post"}}
                <span class="nav-post-title {{#unless @site.logo}}dash{{/unless}}">{{post.title}}</span>
            {{/is}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="site-nav-right">
    <img id="ss360-search-trigger" src="https://cdn.sitesearch360.com/ss360-search-icon.png" style="cursor:pointer;position: relative;top:4px;" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3037143943" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    {{#if @site.secondary_navigation}}
        {{navigation type="secondary"}}
    {{else}}
```

**default.hbs** (SiteSearch360 script)

```
<!-- Beginning of SS360 scripts -->

<script>var ss360Config={siteId:"www.monstermtn.com",showResultLink:true,showErrors:true,layout:{navigation:{position:"top"},mobile:{showUrl:true},desktop:{showUrl:true}},suggestions:{show:false},style:{themeColor:"#00843c",defaultCss:true,themeColor:'#313648'},searchBox:{placeholder:"lorem ipsum",selector:"#query"},results:{fullScreenConfig:{trigger:"#ss360-search-trigger",caption:"LOREM IPSUM"},caption:"Search results for your query #QUERY#",moreResultsPagingSize:5},tracking:{enhanced:false}};</script>
<script src="https://cdn.sitesearch360.com/v13/sitesearch360-v13.min.js" async></script>

    {{!-- Ghost outputs important scripts and data with this tag - it should always be the very last thing before the closing body tag --}}
    {{ghost_foot}}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your icon usage have you:

1. Made sure FontAwesome is being referenced / imported?
2. Styled the icon appropriately?
3. Made sure to use the right attributes like so:

   ```html
   <i id="ss360-search-trigger" class="fas fa-search" style="cursor:pointer" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3037143943" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);"></i>
   ```